# Knock out viewmodel changed

Tags: jquery, mvvm, knockout.js

I am trying to create a scenario using knockout that monitors the view model for changes and notifies any subscribers that the change occurred, this works fine and the notification is fired off, however then I change views and the view model changes the notification is fired again, it is like when the view model is being disposed the properties are still being observed, is there any way around this behavior.

```
            var options = {
            callback: function () {
                var type = "modelChanged";
                var subscription = $.config.core._subscriptions[type];
                if (subscription) {
                    $.config.core._subscriptions[type] = null;
                }
                self.savePersonalInformation();
            },
            event: "forceSave",
            moduleId: "MemberInformationPersonalInfo"
        };
        $.config.core.subscribeView(options);
```

Note: subscribe view is a custom extender that is basically a wrapper around subscribe.

```
    monitorPropertyValues: function (model) {
        //subscribe to each property in the model to monitor changes to the value
        // loop through all the properties in the model
        for (var property in model) {
            if (model.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
                if (model[property].subscribe) { //subcribe to observable properties
                    // subscribe to changes
                    model[property].subscribe(function(value) {
                        if (value) {
                            $.config.core.notifySubscribers(true, "modelChanged");
                        }
                    });
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

MonitorPropertyValues is called when the view is initialized.

The basic behavior I am trying to achieve is as follows, I have a list of tabs on the page each tab has its own view model. When I click on a tab I want to check if there has been changes within the view model. If there has I want to send a notification to the the view model to save all changes.

Comment: @Tyrsius I am not trying to rewrite the core I am trying to extend it, but I can not seem to unsubscribe my properties from the modelChange notification.  I have tried setting the _subscription array to empty but not working.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this sort of functionality with a `computed` that automatically touches all the properties (this is done using ko.toJS, which walks your viewmodel). This is simpler than your extension, and shouldn't have any disposing issues.

```
var viewModel = {
    data: {
        first: ko.observable("Ted"),
        last: ko.observable("Smith") 
    },
    isChanged: ko.observable(false)
}

viewModel.allChanges = ko.computed(function() {
   ko.toJS(viewModel.data);  //just touches all observables, that's it.
});

viewModel.allChanges.subscribe(function() {
    if (!viewModel.isChanged()) {
        viewModel.isChanged(true);     
    }
});

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);​
```

This solution was taken from a fiddle by RP Niemeyer, but I can't find the original now. Anyway, credit goes to him.